# Incorrect normal for implicitly defined cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a cone defined by
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{(z-h)^2}{h^2} = 0$$

From what I understand, even for this being defined implicitly, I should be able to find a normal vector to the surface by taking the partial derivatives.

So I have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{2x}{a^2} \qquad
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=\frac{2y}{b^2} \qquad
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=-\frac{2(z-h)}{h^2} \quad
$$

So I believe the normal vector should be
$$\frac{(\frac{2x}{a^2},\frac{2y}{b^2},-\frac{2(z-h)}{h^2})}{\sqrt((\frac{2x}{a^2})^2+(\frac{2y}{b^2})^2+(-\frac{2(z-h)}{h^2})^2)}$$

Is this the correct method? I suspect I may be missing something as I've graphed a solution I calculated by hand and it does not look to be orthogonal to the cone's surface.

Comment: This is a terrible picture. How do we see a cone? Anyhow, 3D perspective will rarely represent a right angle as a literal right angle. However, your algebra is suspect.  You are missing sets of parentheses all over the denominator. Skip the denominator unless you truly need a unit normal vector.

Comment: The $x, y$, and $z$ scales do not even seem to be the same in that image, so I wouldn't put much trust in it.

Comment: I appreciate both of your answers, I think I will remove the picture as to focus on whether the method is correct or not, however I suspect it is not correct.